# Spring Data JPA/Hibernate handling associations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need based on parameter retrieve or not some associations from an entity. In the bellow example I need to get the records list only if a parameter is passed through my api. Can you recommend a way of achieving this using hibernate/spring data? I'm looking for the most clean and spring data-like approach.

```
public class Customer {
  private UUID id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer") 
  private List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Record {
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "customer_id", length = 36, columnDefinition = "varchar(36)", nullable = false)
    private UUID customerId;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

My Repository is empty:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, UUID> {  }
```

On my service I'm doing something like:

```
Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(customerId).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomerNotFoundException("customerId", customerId));
```

But what I would like to do is something like:

```
if (showRecords) {
    Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(customerId).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomerNotFoundException("customerId", customerId));
} else {
    Customer customer = customerRepository.findByIdWithoutAssociations(customerId).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomerNotFoundException("customerId", customerId));
}
```

Comment: as a side note, why do you have both `UUID customerId;` and `Customer customer;` in your `Record` class?

Comment: I use the UUID one just to queries. Because with the Customer one I will need to have an instance of that if I need to make the query, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the base `findById` to return just the Customer object and have another method `findWithRecordsById` to return customer+records using `@EntityGraph`?

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, UUID>{

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"records"})
    Customer findWithRecordsById(UUID id);
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I was not aware of this @EntityGraph. I will take a look at it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly. When I call the default findById it also returns the Records associated.

Comment: Does it return in same/single query?

Comment: I can see two lines of hibernate log resulting from calling the base findById: 
Hibernate: select customer0_.id as id1_1_0_,...... from CUSTOMER customer0_ where customer0_.id=?
Hibernate: select records0_.customer_id as customer5_2_0_,..... from RECORD records0_ where records0_.customer_id=?

Comment: That's the thing... it fetches the records in separate query when you try to access it. @EntityGraph fetches the full object-graph in single query with  all child tables  that you put in attributePaths `attributePaths = {"childTbl1", "childTbl2" }`

Comment: Ok sorry I understood the problem. I was using the lombok @Data which generates a toString method printing the records and it was being called without I've noticed. Ok thanks I will look at the EntityGraph part