# How to issue one query instead of multiple queries for graph of entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data repository where I'm getting all positions for a set of accounts:

```
public interface PositionRepository extends JpaRepository<Position, PositionKey> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "Position.all", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Position> findByAccountIn(Set<Account> accounts);
    
}
```

`Position` has attributes that are also entities (a few nested levels):

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Position.all",
attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("account", subgraph = "Account.all"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("product", subgraph = "Product.all")
})

@Data
public class Position {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PositionKey positionKey; 

    @MapsId("accountId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId")
    private Account account;
    
    @MapsId("productId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    private Product product;           
}

@Embeddable
@Data
public class PositionKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "accountId")
    private Long accountId;
    
    @Column(name = "productId")
    private Long productId;
}


@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(includeAllAttributes = true, name = "Product.all",
    attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode(value = "vendor", subgraph = "Vendor.all"),
                      @NamedAttributeNode(value = "type", subgraph = "ProductType.all")}
)
@Data
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeId")
    private ProductType type;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vendorCode")
    private Vendor vendor;
    
}

@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Account.all")
@Data
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "accountId")
    private Long id;
    
}
```

I'm always returning the full entity graph of positions as serialized JSON to a client. So, I'm always going to need all attributes and nested attributes. The position instances are 350 max.

Despite using `@NamedEntityGraph`, I noticed that individual queries are still being issued. For example, I get a query for each unique vendor. It usually takes ~2-3 seconds to get the results from all the individual queries.

How can I tell JPA to issue one query with multiple joins? I can manually write this SQL (using multiple joins) and it returns in just a few milliseconds.

**Update**

The data is accessed as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/position")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PositionController {

    private final PositionRepository positionRepo;
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Position> getAllPositions(Set<Account> accounts) {
        return positionRepo.findByAccountIn(account);
    }
    
}
```

When the list of positions is returned, they are serialized via Jackson. So, it's Jackson that actually accesses the data.

Comment: If you access a childEntity(loop. print, log) it will fetch from DB if it was not already fetched. I think you should review your code to make sure how the result of the query is being used? If you need the child entities downstream, its better to fetch it early(together with the parent object).

Comment: Also, I answered similar question couple hours back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013319/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-handling-associations

Comment: @gtiwari333 - Thanks for the response. Yes, I need the child entities downstream, so I'm trying to fetch early by using a single join query. I've look at your answer in the other post. I tried using attributePaths instead of the value element in `@EntityGraph`, but hibernate still issues multiple select statements as noted in OP.

Comment: Can you share your code where/how you are accessing data?

Comment: @gtiwari333 - OP updated.